# two of your men

Tags: negation

Can one use

a. Two of your men did not save him. His daughters saved him.

instead of

b. It wasn't two of your men who saved him. It was his daughters.

?

The idea is that the statement **'Two of your men saved him.**' is **not true**. The people who saved him were his daughters.

Many thanks.

Comment: Both your men couldn't save him. His daughters saved him.

Answer (score 1):

"Two of your men did not save him" suggests that *others* of your men did.

If only two were available and neither of them did the saving, it would be more idiomatic to say, "Your two men did not save him. His daughters saved him."